# How to realize an algorithm to filter IPv4 adress without regex?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to realize an algorithm to filter IPv4 address. It should be work with **decimal**, **hexadecimal**, **octal** notation **with dots** and **without**. Also, **I can't use regex**.

Examples:

1. 192.0.2.235           return **True**
2. 0xC0.0x00.0x02.0xEB   return **True**
3. 256.256.256.256       return **False**
4. 0300.0000.0002.0353   return **True**
5. 0xC00002EB            return **True**
6. 3221226219            return **True**
7. 030000001353          return **True**

I'm trying to do code like below but it's doesn't work for all examples

```
    def convertor(s):
        s = s.split('.')
        if len(s) != 4:
            return False
        for i in s:
            if not i.isdigit():
                i = int(i,16)
                list.append(i)
            else:
                if int(i) < 0 and int(i) > 255:
                    print('This is not correct IPv4')
                    return False
                else:
                    i = int(i)
                    list.append(i)
        print('This is correct IPv4')
        return list


    def convert(ip):
        n = 4
        ip = str(int(ip,32))
        ip = [ip[i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(ip),n)]
        return convertor(ip)

    print(convert('3221226219'))
```

Any advice?

Comment: Can you show us *how* you use this code and which examples don't work? You should also fix the indentation, because the code you've given doesn't run.

Comment: He wants this: https://gist.github.com/kkirsche/2e2d6d1dd8c6d27c3a7e but without regex :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing that comes to mind:

```
MAX_DEC = 4294967295
MAX_QUAD_DEC = 255

def is_quad_ip(ip):
  """
  Validates IPs in quad decimal, octal and hexadecimal
  Ex.
  127.0.0.1
  0x7f.0x0.0x0.0x1
  :param ip: ip to validate
  :type ip: string
  :return: true if it is a valid ip in quad decimal, octal or hexadecimal; false otherwise
  :type return: boolean
  """
  ll = ip.split(".")
  if len(ll) != 4:
    return False
  try:
    is_dec = all([
      0 <= int(x) <= MAX_QUAD_DEC
      and (len(x) == 1 or (len(x) >= 2 and not x.startswith("0")))
      for x in ll
    ])
  except ValueError:
    is_dec = False
  try:
    is_oct = all([
      len(x) == 4
      and 0 <= int(x, 8) <= MAX_QUAD_DEC
      for x in ll
    ])
  except ValueError:
    is_oct = False
  try:
    is_hex = all([0 <= int(x, 16) <= MAX_QUAD_DEC for x in ll])
  except ValueError:
    is_hex = False
  return is_dec or is_oct or is_hex

def is_ip(ip):
  """
  Validates IPs either in quad notation or not
  Ex.
  127.0.0.1 (QUAD DECIMAL)
  2130706433 (DECIMAL)
  :param ip: ip to validate
  :type ip: string
  :return: true if it is a valid ip; false otherwise
  :type return: boolean
  """
  if is_quad_ip(ip):
    return True
  try:
    is_dec = 0 <= int(ip) <= MAX_DEC
  except ValueError:
    is_dec = False
  try:
    is_oct = 0 <= int(ip, 8) <= MAX_DEC
  except ValueError:
    is_oct = False
  try:
    is_hex = 0 <= int(ip, 16) <= MAX_DEC
  except ValueError:
    is_hex = False
  return is_dec or is_oct or is_hex

print(is_ip("192.0.2.235"))
print(is_ip("0xC0.0x00.0x02.0xEB"))
print(is_ip("256.256.256.256"))
print(is_ip("0300.0000.0002.0353"))
print(is_ip("0xC00002EB"))
print(is_ip("3221226219"))
print(is_ip("030000001353"))
```

Returns:

```
True
True
False
True
True
True
True
```

Comment: Great! Thank you!